# Why can't I create my Datasource with JavaConfig in Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Can someone please tell me what I am missing I am trying to use JavaConfig in a Spring MVC project to setup the following database but I cant set the driverClass, user, password etc?

Can someone please tell me why

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    DataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    try {
        ds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUser("jboss");
        ds.setPassword("xoJ4u0Hs");
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://6dhdbm01/jboss1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return ds;
}
```

I FIXED IT: I HAD TO CHANGE THE CODE TO THIS:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

         // com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource ds = new com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource();

        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();


        try {

            /*

            This was old code for using C3P0 Database pooling
            ds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setUser("jboss");
            ds.setPassword("xoJ4u0Hs");
            ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://6dhdbm01/jboss1");
            */

            ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            ds.setUsername("jboss");
            ds.setPassword("xoJ4u0Hs");
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://6dhdbm01/jboss1");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

But I am getting this error.. Am I missing something in maven pom.xml

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool
```

Comment: What is happening, exception being thrown, failing to inject, ect.  Need more information =)

Comment: no this code will not build! It can find, setDriveClass, setUser, etc

Comment: Post the build error, then.

Comment: Good luck out there, enjoy Spring =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guesses:

- You're importing javax.activation.DataSource rather than javax.sql.DataSource
- com.mysql.jdbc.Driver isn't on classpath
- URL / Credentials are wrong

But really don't have much to go off of, first guess is a compile time issue, second two are deploy time issues.

EDIT:
Can't find what symbol?  My guess is DriverManagerDataSource as it is not part of core, it's part of spring-jdbc.  Also, wouldn't really recommend that DataSource implementation as it isn't a connection pool, it creates a new connection each time, look into `commons-dbcp`

Comment: He's getting `cannot find symbol`, meaning there is no such method or field in `DataSource` class, so it's probably the first.

Comment: I fixed that issue please see above

Comment: Good job, could you accept the answer as we guided you to the solution, and to get it off the unanswered tag, please?

Comment: you did not give me the anwser! I still have issues

Comment: Oh, add commons-dbcp as a dependency in maven, if you're not using maven, add commons-dbcp and commons-pool to your classpath.

Comment: I have commons-dbcp in my pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: that's a snapshot build, use version 1.4